# Can't access public folder because PUBLIC_URL is empty (create-react-app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, dotenv

I created `create-react-app`. Now I need to display images from my public folder. (path from public folder is stored in `product.image` variable.)

As i read in [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) I should use such code:

```
<img
  src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + product.image.desktop}
  alt={product.name}
/>
```

But `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` is empty.

When i write code without `env` variable it works perfectly.

```
src={"http://localhost:3000" + product.image.desktop}
```

This is output from `console.log(process.env)`:

```
{ 
  NODE_ENV: "development",
  PUBLIC_URL: "",
  WDS_SOCKET_HOST: undefined,
  WDS_SOCKET_PATH: undefined,
  WDS_SOCKET_PORT: undefined,
  FAST_REFRESH: true 
}
```

How can I make PUBLIC_URL valid in production and localhost too?